# libpipewire-module-combine-stream no longer working as expected in 23.10

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, 23.10, pipewire

I upgraded to Ubuntu 23.10 from 23.04 yesterday. I have a custom wireplumber config setup under ~/.config/pipewire/pipewire.conf.d/combined21.conf to create a combined sink. Basically I want to create a 2.1 system using two sound cards. My config file is below. In 23.04 this worked perfectly, but after upgrading, the LFE no longer produces sound when playing audio from any application (except system settings). I can open the sound settings and use the "Test" and the LFE will produce sound from there. But other applications do not send any signal to the LFE channel. What changed? And how do I keep up on these things so I don't have to keep asking?

```
context.modules = [
{   name = libpipewire-module-combine-stream
    args = {
        combine.mode = sink
        node.name = "combine_source_2_1"
        node.description = "My 2.1 Combine"
        combine.latency-compensate = false
        combine.props = {
            audio.position = [ FL FR LFE ]
        }
        stream.props = {
                stream.dont-remix = false
        }
        stream.rules = [
            {   matches = [
                    {   media.class = "Audio/Sink"
                        node.name = "alsa_output.pci-0000_04_00.6.HiFi__hw_Generic_1__sink"
                    } ]
                actions = { create-stream = {
                        audio.position = [ FL FR ]
                        combine.audio.position = [ FL FR ]
                } } }
            {   matches = [
                    {   media.class = "Audio/Sink"
                        node.name = "alsa_output.usb-0d8c_USB_Sound_Device-00.analog-stereo"
                    } ]
                actions = { create-stream = {
                        audio.position = [ FR ]
                        combine.audio.position = [ LFE ]
                } } }
        ]
    }
}
]
```

Comment: Can you run `helvum` and see if the outputs are wired properly?

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not sure exactly what did it. But I had a file under ~/.config/wireplumber/50-alsa-config.lua which I had added simply to set the `["session.suspend-timeout-seconds"] = 0` so I would stop getting popping sounds. I removed that, since that file with the exact same settings exists under /etc/wireplumber with that setting in 23.10. Restarting pipewire didn't do anything, but a system reboot did. There was no difference between my local user alsa-config and what's in etc, but whatever.